# Flutter: _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Tags: flutter, null

Can someone help with this error? print() retrieve me the data from firebase but when I try to access them in the widegt the erros apears

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrmSj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What really happened is, you're trying to use a value, which is `null`, but, the `Text` widget is expecting a `string`, rather than `null`. This is the root cause of your error.

You can fix the error by making sure your data is not null or you can use a null safe operator on your nullable data.

Example:

```
Text(userData['name'] ?? 'name not found')
```

Happy coding :D

Comment: Thanks! null safe operator works for me, I think my data is not null becouse I asign dummy data when I create the user.